# How to show Events for selected month in MBCalendarkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mbcalendarkit

I am using MBCalendarkit for showing custom calendar in my app. But I unable to show events on calendar. Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of MBCalendarKit.

Have a look at the documentation in the [README](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/README.md). It's been updated since this question was asked, and hopefully it's more clear. There's also newer sample code in the repository.